# HTML5 JavaScript, How can I clear my input field every time I hit the spacebar so there is only ever max 1 word showing in the input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 input fields where the second is a copy of the first using this code.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("paragraph-text"),
    dst = document.getElementById("copy");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value;
    });
};
```

For every key I press when filling the first field, it shows up in the second filed. However, I'd like to have only 1 word show up at a time in the second (copy) field, meaning I want the field to clear every time I hit the spacebar (or keycode 32). Could someone help me out please.

It probably doesn't matter but here are the 2 html fields:

```
<input type="text" id="paragraph-text" name="paragraph-text" placeholder="type here to begin...">
<input type="text" id="copy" name="copy">
```

I tried this in the JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("paragraph-text"),
    dst = document.getElementById("copy");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value;
        window.onkeydown = function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                src.value += ' '
                dst.value = ''
                if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

and it works except for the fact that when I type the next word, the original word is still there, so if i type a long sentence, the copy field will still contain all the words from the paragraph-text field, even though it does clear temporarily with every spacebar press. I would like it to stay cleared so the next word is alone, and so on. There should only ever be 1 word or nothing in the copy field.

Comment: Why are you binding onkeydown to the window object and why are you binding it EVERY time src input changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure I understand what you actually want, but I think this might be what you're after?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("paragraph-text"),
    dst = document.getElementById("copy");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value.split(' ').pop();
    });
};
```

The **first** input might contain a *word*, or a *sentence* containing multiple *words* separated by *whitespaces*.

The **second** input should contain the last *word* from the **first** input.

We convert the contents of the first input to an *array of words* using `split(' ')` and then `pop()` to return the last item.

Comment: Maybe to tune it little bit for special cases of inserting text or typing multiple spaces use regular expression and split text by one or more `whitespace` characters `src.split(/\s+/)`